# Deserialize json string back to expando using JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I'm creating a json object on the fly ( *without* Json.net ) via :

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Age = 42;
expando.Name = "Royi";
expando.Childrens = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Childrens.First = "John";
```

Which looks like :

[image]

And so , I can query it like  :

```
Console.WriteLine (expando.Name); //Royi
```

Ok , so let's serialize it  :

```
var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(expando);
Console.WriteLine (jsonString);
```

Result :

```
[{"Key":"Age","Value":42},{"Key":"Name","Value":"Royi"},{"Key":"Childrens","Value":[{"Key":"First","Value":"John"}]}]
```

*Notice how expando ( which is Idictionary of string,object) is keeping data*

**Question**

Now I want the string to be deserialized back to :

[image]

I have tried :

```
var jsonDeserizlied = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(jsonString);
```

But  :

*Type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' is not supported for deserialization of an array.*

So , How can I get

```
 [{"Key":"Age","Value":42},{"Key":"Name","Value":"Royi"},{"Key":"Childrens","Value":[{"Key":"First","Value":"John"}]}]
```

back to expando representation ?

nb

*we don't use JSON.net.*

**update**

I have managed to  change `object[]` to `IList<IDictionary<string,object>>`:

```
 var jsonDeserizlied = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<IDictionary<string,object>>>(jsonString);
```

Which is now :

[image]

but again , I need to transform it to  :

[image]

Comment: Will [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13642873/706456) work for you? Once it's an object you can then convert it to expando, right?

Comment: no. see here why http://i.imgur.com/1PnZ4T2.png ( The problem is becuase Array structure)

Comment: Rather then deserialising through Expando have you tried `Dictionary<String, Object>`? As in `var jsonDeserizlied = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<String, Object>>(jsonString);`

Comment: @PeterSmith I believe it's the same thing. Expando implements IDictionary<string, object>,

Comment: @PeterSmith http://i.imgur.com/EnAHA8o.png

Comment: I believe ToDictionary is needed here.

Comment: @James No. http://i.imgur.com/AyONzxV.png

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think you will ultimately need to rebuild your `ExpandoObject` from your dictionary, here's one [example](https://gist.github.com/theburningmonk/2221646) of how that can be done.

Comment: @James look here http://i.imgur.com/Ft0Gqc6.png .I believbe simgle line of Linq code can transform it to dictionary.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm confused, your question suggests you already have it serialized as a `Dictionary<string,object>`, aren't you now looking for a way to convert it back to `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: @James Expando or dictionary<string,object> , it doesnt matter.  If I have it as single Idictionary<string,object> then I could cast it to expando. Exapmle : If I have `var t=(IDictionary<string,object>)expando;` then I will be able to do  : `ExpandoObject  lll = (ExpandoObject)t;` . but Look how messy is http://i.stack.imgur.com/JOef2.png . it is not a single object which I can treat it as single key value

Comment: @RoyiNamir ah... I see what you mean, it's not serialized each property in a *single* dictionary, it's broken them down into 3 separate ones. That would appear more an issue with how the serializer generates the JSON because, technically, the representation of your JSON isn't suggesting it's a single object. Have you tried casting your `ExpandoObject` to `Dictionary<string, object>` first and *then* deserializing to JSON?

Comment: My though on this is that your are wanting to deserialize into a dynamic object without knowing what that structure of the object is. For me, this implies two options. One - define a class to hold the object rather than Expando, OR - write a generic method to build your dynamic structure. This would recursively iterate through the List; if the value is a value type then stay at the same level (an Expando value); if the value is an object then you need a new level (an Expando child)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got It.

First let's deal with the fact that it is an `IEnumerable<>`  Json representation ( because of how `ExpandoObject` gets serialized via `JavaScriptSerializer`) , so :

```
var jsonDeserizlied = new   JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>>>(jsonString);
 Console.WriteLine (jsonDeserizlied);
```

I've also written this recursive function which creates `ExpandoObject` and sub sub expandos recursively :

```
public ExpandoObject go( IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>> lst)
{

 return lst.Aggregate(new ExpandoObject(),
                           (aTotal,n) => {
                                (aTotal    as IDictionary<string, object>).Add(n["Key"].ToString(), n["Value"] is object[] ? go(  ((object[])n["Value"]).Cast<IDictionary<string,Object>>())  :n["Value"] );
                                return aTotal;
                           });

}
```

Yes , I know it can be improved but I just want to show the idea.

So now we invoke it via :

```
var tt=   go(jsonDeserizlied);
```

Result :

[image]

**Exactly** What I wanted.

```
Console.WriteLine (tt.Age ); //52
```